# What is the best ram-efficient way to put high res images into numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am currently working on processing images for use in a `GAN` but I have yet found a `ram-efficient way` to put 30,000 images into an `Numpy array` for easy use. Any help would be appreciated.

Framework I am using: `Tensorflow`

Comment: probably the best you can do is to read them in batches from your disk.. I think there's no way to get that size of images in memory

Comment: Can you possibly explain how to do it?

Comment: it's hard to explain with almost 0 context, what libraries are you using (tensorflow, pytorch, other?? where you have all the images?

Comment: which deep learning framework are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's assume, you have disk space for those 30000 images (pretty obvious).

The rest of the answer should be "use batches". You never want to keep all the 30000 images in your memory as it's pretty space inefficient. Besides, you must be training the GAN with a GPU.

So, keep the images in the drive. Use batching, few images per mini-batch, load it to CPU (RAM), do some pre-processing, move it to GPU, train, and continue.